# HTML input and button not same width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a weird problem at the moment, my `input` and `button` tags have the same width on them (`width: 341.5px;` calculated from `$(window).width() / 4`) in code, but they are no where near the same width in sight. Here is what I mean:

[image]

(The dark theme thing is from my GTK theme).

Why does it do this?

```js
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var screenHeight = $(window).height();
$(".userName").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
$(".passWord").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
$(".submit").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.userName {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8A80;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 16px;
}

.passWord {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8A80;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 16px;
}

.submit {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FF8A80;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
  background-color: #FF8A80;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="userName" class="userName" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your username here" required autofocus />
<br />
<input type="password" name="passWord" class="passWord" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your password here" required />
<br />
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" title="Click this button if you are sure your information is right">Submit</button>
<br />
```

Comment: Please include relevant codes in the question

Comment: Please share your code also.

Comment: padding maybe ?

Comment: Your question is incomplete unless you share your HTML / CSS code

Comment: Sorry, I was adding it, and got sidetracked. Why the down votes D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy pasted your code and only added 1 block of css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* OR */

input, button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Run the code snippet below.

```js
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var screenHeight = $(window).height();
$(".userName").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
$(".passWord").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
$(".submit").css("width", screenWidth / 4);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}

.userName {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8A80;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 16px;
}

.passWord {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8A80;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 16px;
}

.submit {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FF8A80;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
    background-color: #FF8A80;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="userName" class="userName" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your username here" required autofocus  />
<br />
<input type="password" name="passWord" class="passWord" title="This area is for your unique username" placeholder="Your password here" required />
<br />
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" title="Click this button if you are sure your information is right" >Submit</button>
<br />
```

The default value of `box-sizing` property for all elements is `content-box`.

With this value, the width and height of an element is calculated irrelevant to its padding and border. Therefore, an element with `width: 10px` and `padding: 5px` is actually `15px` wide in display.

By making its `box-sizing` property `border-box`, it includes the padding and border into calculation. Therefore `width: 10px` and `padding: 5px` is actually `10px` wide only in display (though its content inside becomes `0px` wide because padding from both sides occupied `5px` each).

Learn more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

**Note:** `margin` value will not affect either case.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Sorry, I forgot to add the JQuery link into the question, but I do have it (I'm not that idiotic :P)

Comment: @JacobCollins no prob for the jQuery since it's not what caused your problem. Updated my answer to include explanations. Do mark my answer as correct too if you find it helpful. ;)